# Can a sentence begin with the word "Advocates"?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-structure

I am currently writing up a persuasive essay, one of the sentences is as follows.

> Advocates and non-advocates of change, we must show reconciliation towards the rightful owners.

My advisor mentioned that you cannot start a sentence with *advocates*. As far as I know, *advocate* is a noun, even adding an s makes it a plural noun. So why am I not allowed to start a sentence with *advocates*? Is it the context itself?

Comment: Hope the adviser elaborates on his reservations. Let's see what happens.

Comment: Perhaps the advisor was focusing on ease of readability. You could improve readability a bit by removing ", we". Or by adding adding "As" at the beginning. There's nothing inherently wrong with beginning a sentence with "Advocates".

Comment: I think you should include the sentence that comes before. On this sentence alone, I'd be tempted to start it with "**As** advocates, and non-advocates of change, we ..." because it makes more sense, it's not about grammaticality but about making sense.

Comment: P.S I had not read iMerchant's comment or suggestion before adding my comment, and we're saying the same thing.

Comment: It is the start of my clincher. A rhetorical question comes before the quoted sentence. It is directed towards the whole paragraph.

Comment: "Advocates of change" is a noun phrase, and refers to a general idea of people who campaign for a change in the laws, rights, beliefs etc of a system. You group this with people who don't want to change/modify the system, (which seems a bit odd to me),  by placing the pronoun "we" you are including both yourself and the reader in these two categories. Thus I would begin my sentence with *Be we advocates of change, or not, we must show...* Or simply eliminate the "we" in your original sentence. It works better.

Comment: Your advisor is likely thinking of advocates as a verb.  The comments by iMerchant and Mari-Lou are a good solution if your intention is to refer inclusively to a group and make an observation.  If the sentence is more of a suggestion or command and you are addressing it to advocates and non-advocates, the current wording does that.

Comment: How can an advisor say that starting with Advocates is wrong without offering a correction? Just as comments by iMerchant and Mari-Lou offer good edits, your advisor owes you the courtesy of a better version of the sentence -- both to serve as a teachable moment and to prove that it's not you-wrong-n-I-no-gotta-explain.

Comment: Another reason for changing the sentence somehow is that it is ambiguous as it stands. It might be *addressed to* 'advocates and non-advocates of change', in the same way as 'Ladies and gentlemen, we must ...'

Answer (score 2):

Your tutor is wrong. They are assuming you mean the *verb* 'advocate' (to advocate) when you are using it as a *noun* (persons who advocate something).

Of course, you *can* begin a sentence with a verb, including '*to advocate*' - for example, "advocate the wrong man and you will be derided". However, your tutor is mistaking the plural form of the noun 'advocates' for the third person singular form of the verb, which couldn't be used without a subject (eg "*he* advocates").

The noun and the verb, although obviously related, are pronounced differently.

Therefore, your sentence is correct (but check your spelling of 'rightful').

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason why you might not start a sentence with Advocate or Advocates as a single or plural noun. However, it would be improper to start a sentence with the same words as a verb.

"**Advocates will meet at 5pm to ratify the agreement.**" would be okay.

"**The committee has formed a plan. Advocates five of the proposed changes.**" would not be correct despite being understandable as an informal note.

Comment: I completely agree, hence, why I do not understand his reasoning. In my case, it is in fact, a plural noun.

Comment: I think you mean you do NOT understand his reasoning? There's nothing grammatically wrong with the way you started that sentence. Perhaps the problem somehow lies in the context?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your sentence is correct. While I do not know what your advisor thinks, I assume he sees a "poetic-like" structure of the sentence (as I do). It may be just a tad more "academic" to say:

> We, advocates and non-advocates of change, must show reconciliation towards the rightful owners.